# How to create an array of tkinter text input, where every line in text is an element in array

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code:

```
def full_function():
    options=text.get(1.0, END)
    print options

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

text = Text(root,font=("Purisa",12))
text.pack()

button=Button(root, text ="Button", command =lambda: full_function())
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

How could I make this program to create an array of text input, so every line of text would be an element in array. For example, if input is:

```
                                              I am here.

                                              They are there.
```

Then i want my app to create following list=`["I am here.", "They are there."]`

Comment: Have you tried anything? What problems are you having when trying to save the strings to a list?

Comment: Have you considered `str.splitlines`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from Tkinter import *

#Below should pack to class
class MyWindow:
    def __init__(self, wname=""):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title(wname)
        self.text = Text(self.root,font=("Purisa",12))
        self.text.pack()

        self.button=Button(self.root, text ="Button", command=self.prn)
        self.button.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def get_words_list(self, widget):
        """Return list of words"""
        options=widget.get(1.0, END)# get lines into string
        #Remove spaces in list of lines
        return [i.strip() for i in options.splitlines()]

    def prn(self):
        """Testing get_words_list"""
        print self.get_words_list(self.text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = MyWindow("My window")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` to make a list of the input and use `str(text.get(1.0, END))` to remove `unicode "u"`:

```
def full_function():
    options = str(text.get(1.0, END))
    lines = options.strip().split("\n")
    print lines
['I am here.', 'They are there.']
```